# "plot.new has not been called yet" error in rmarkdown (Rstudio 1.0.44)

Tags: r, plot, rstudio, r-markdown

I am using a recent version of Rstudio with an iMac

> Version 1.0.44 – © 2009-2016 RStudio, Inc. Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh;
>   Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/602.2.14 (KHTML, like Gecko)

And I noticed the notebook function for rmarkdown files. When generating plots, the usual "Plots window" is not used any more, and the plots are generated just below the code chunk.

And I have an error for the following code:

```
plot(seq(1,10,1))
abline(a=0,b=1)
```

The error is showed below the code chunk :

```
Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) : plot.new has not been called yet
```

However, when knitting the whole rmarkdown file, there is no error.

So I would like to know how to avoid the error:

- by using another code
- by using the "Plots window"
- or another way.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. Only if I put both commands in seperate chunks the error appears.

Comment: I think that it is because I run the code line by line. When runing the entire R chunk in rmarkdown, I don't get errors.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The following will work

```
{plot(seq(1,10,1))
 abline(a=0,b=1)}
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: I don't really get why it works either, but can verify that it does. Must have something to do with the Rstudio markdown environment.

Comment: Wrapping it in curly brackets ensures all lines are evaluated as one block. This answer, to an unrelated question, explains it nicely. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28758675/1454785

Answer (score 8):

In RStudio, there's a setting in Preferences -> R Markdown to "Show output inline for all R Markdown documents".  To get rid of the error, make sure this is unchecked.

Answer (score 5):

This works too

```
plot(seq(1,10,1))+
abline(a=0,b=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

In jupyter with R kernel, you will see that error if run the code line by line, just as XR SC mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

This was happening to me because I was adding an invalid parameter to my plot. In my case I was trying to execute:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=sales)) + geom_histogram() + title('Plot Title')
```

And should have been executing:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=sales)) + geom_histogram() + ggtitle('Plot Title')
```

Notice that you must use `ggtitle`, not `title`.