# Problems in creating function in R

Tags: r, function

I am new to R and I am trying to create simple UDFs in R. Every time I try to create one, I get the error "

> Error: unexpected symbol in:".

Not sure where I am going wrong. 
Here are a few examples of the functions that I was creating

Function 1

```
addPercent <- function(x) {
   percent <- round (x *100, digits  = 1) result<- paste(percent, "%", sep="") return(result)
}
```

Function 2

```
avg<- function(x) { s <- sum(x) n <- length(x) s/n }
```

Would really appreciate any kind of help to solve this minor issue. 
Thank you much in advance

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is a formatting issue here on SO or if this is your actual issue; either use `;` to separate multiple commands or use new lines. So `avg` should read `avg <- function(x) { s <- sum(x); n <- length(x); s/n }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand from my comment:

In R you have to separate statements either with `;` (semicolon) or with a newline.

So this works:

```
avg <- function(x) { s <- sum(x); n <- length(x); s/n }
avg(c(1, 2, 3))
#[1] 2
```

As does this

```
avg <- function(x) { 
    s <- sum(x)
    n <- length(x)
    s/n 
}
avg(c(1, 2, 3))
#[1] 2
```

To pre-empt the question "What's the difference?", see the following post: [What's the difference in using a semicolon or explicit new line in R code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28758225/whats-the-difference-in-using-a-semicolon-or-explicit-new-line-in-r-code)
.